# Why windows 7 discarding DHCPv6 solicit message intended for my application?

Tags: windows

In my application i am expecting a dhcpv6 solicit message from a linux VM. I can see the packets in wireshark(promiscous mode), but windows is discarding it. Can anyone help me regarding this? Link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2exj591fflvqrh/DHCPv6_Solicit.pcapng?dl=0

Comment: How would you expect those packets to arrive in your application? Can you show the relevant networking code? If at all possible in a self-contained example?

Comment: ServIPv6Add = "fd00::160";
Sock = socket ( AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
SOCKADDR_IN6 SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6 ;
UtilInetPton (AF_INET6, "ff02::1:2", (void *)&mreqLinkScoped.ipv6mr_multiaddr) ;
UtilInetPton (AF_INET6, "ff05::1:3", (void *)&mreqSiteScoped.ipv6mr_multiaddr) ;
mreqLinkScoped.ipv6mr_interface = 26 ;
mreqSiteScoped.ipv6mr_interface = 26 ;
SockAddr.sin6_port = htons(547);

Comment: UtilInetPton (AF_INET6, ServIPv6Add.c_str(), (void *)&SockAddr.sin6_addr) ;
setsockopt(Sock,IPPROTO_IPV6,IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, (const char*)&mreqLinkScoped,sizeof(mreqLinkScoped));
setsockopt(Sock,IPPROTO_IPV6,IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, (const char*)&mreqSiteScoped,sizeof(mreqSiteScoped));
int nBindResult = bind(Sock, (struct sockaddr*)&SockAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN6));

Comment: That's unreadable. There's an "edit" button on your question, please use that,